# Hostname is not mapped to the ip address correctly

Tags: linux, networking, wordpress, arch-linux, hosts-file

I recently installed Wordpress on my home server running Arch Linux. Everything else works smoothly except that when try to access the server externally, the style sheet is not rendered. I have read my distribution's wiki and indeed I found a solution. It says it is because my hostname is not mapped to the ip address correctly and I should either change the /etc/hosts file or set up a proxy server https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wordpress#Appearance_is_broken_.28no_styling.29. However, due to my poor understanding on networking and server adminstration, I have no idea what to do? Can someone show me what **exactly** do I have to do?

Thank you

Comment: How are you accessing this site externally? Do you have a public IP address?

Comment: @ngn yes I port-forwarded my server and use my public ip address to access the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need first the hostname for your server. You get that with:

```
~]# uname -n   
myhost.xyz
```

Now you need the IP address for your machine, you get that with the ip command. Your output can differ depending on how many interfaces you have on your server.

```
~]# ip addr show 
10: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 38:ea:a7:93:b4:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.10.25/16 brd 172.29.255.255 scope global bond0
inet6 fe80::3aea:a7ff:fe93:b4b0/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What you need is the second part of the inet line, in this case 192.168.10.25.

Now you need to add that information to the /etc/hosts file. The easiest way to this is using echo and append like this.

```
echo "<your Hostname>   <your IP>" >> /etc/hosts
```

After you have done this, it should work immediately.

Comment: It still does not work. The wiki suggests to set up a proxy server do you think it may be a good idea?

Comment: A proxy is a much more complicated setup, can you please give me the content of your /etc/hosts? That way I can verify the changes are correct in the file.

Comment: '192.168.0.30 mysql.wordpress my_server

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

Comment: ::1 localhost.localdomainn localhost

Comment: this is all I have and plus what should i enter for $database-hostname during the wordpress installation? The default value is localhost

Comment: localhost should be fine. There looks to be an extra ' in front of the first line? That would be causing issues. It might also be that there is some caching interfering, so you might try a reboot of the server and see if that helps.

Comment: the extra ' was a typo. I clear cache every time I reloaded my website. The issue may be the same as suggested here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-displays-fine-locally-but-not-externally-wamp but I have no idea how to change the wp setting

Comment: Something complicatin your case is the fact, that you don't have a public IP address for your machine, but only using the port forwarding on your router. I'm not 100% sure about WP, but it probably means that you have to follow that advice and change your setting your DynDNS URL. Here it tells you how https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL you should be able to do it without having to edit anything in the database